# a look-ahead regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have this string - `[1]{a,b} xxx [3] [4]{e,f}`

I'd like to catch `[1]{a,b}` and `[4]{e,f}` and all other `[.*]{.*}`

When trying `\[.*?\](?!\[)\{.*?\}` I get `[1]{a,b}` and `[3] [4]{e,f}`

I'm using Python 2.7

What is wrong with the look-ahead? I specify not to include the `[` character...
Can it be solved without look-ahead?

Comment: You need lookbehind.

Comment: The lookahead doesn’t make much sense. Just match `\[[^[]*\]\{.*?\}` instead.

Comment: what's wrong with a simple `\[.\]\{.,.\}` ?

Comment: those . should actually be .*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a negated character class, instead of `.*` :

```
>>> s= "[1]{a,b} xxx [3] [4]{e,f}"
>>> 
>>> import re

>>> re.findall(r'\[[^]]*\]\{[^}]*\}',s)
['[1]{a,b}', '[4]{e,f}']
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I guess I'm not that strong with regex :)